# How tu update database using ajax and the PUT verb?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, put

I'm trying to update a property in my database called "Estado". I'm using ajax to do it, like so:

```
  function atualizaBD(idmarcador, novoEstado) {
    $.ajax
        ({
            url: `/api/IgnicoesAPI/${idmarcador}`,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: idmarcador, Estado: novoEstado }),
            async: true,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                 connection.invoke("PostMarker").catch(function (err) {
                              return console.error(err.toString());
                 });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ocorreu um erro!")
            }
        });
}
```

Here is my model:

```
        public class Ignicoes
{

    public Ignicoes()
    {
        ListaOcorrencias = new HashSet<Ocorrencias>();

    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }

    //estado(recusada, aceite, em avaliacao, concluido)
    //public string Estado { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Estado { get; set; }

  
    public DateTime DataInicioPropostaIgnicao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataDecisaoIgnicao { get; set; }


    //lista de ocorrencias 
    public virtual ICollection<Ocorrencias> ListaOcorrencias { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my PUT method:

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> PutIgnicoes([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao)
    {
        
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        if (id != ignicao.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        else
        {
            var dataDecisao = DateTime.Now;
            var ig = _context.Ignicoes.FirstOrDefault(ignicaoId => ignicaoId.Id.Equals(id));
            if (ig != null)
            {
                ig.Estado = ignicao.Estado;
                //ig.Estado = 0;
                //ig.Latitude = ignicao.Latitude;
                //ig.Longitude = ignicao.Longitude;
                ig.DataDecisaoIgnicao = dataDecisao;
            }
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!IgnicoesExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

I already tried to use this code, but instead of changing the property "Estado" I changed the property "Latitude" and it worked perfectly. I don't know why this is happening. Both "Latitude" and "Estado" are the same type - String. Can somebody see the error?
Here is what appears in my output tab:

[image]

Here is the Network Analysis:
[image]

{"errors":{"Latitude":["The Latitude field is required."],"Longitude":["The Longitude field is required."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|43114da6-4594b09a6260f1a2."}

Comment: What value are you passing in novoEstado

Comment: It's a string, It says "aceite". When I call the function atualizaBD, it«s like this - atualizaBD(id, "aceite");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to undestand the problem if you had added ajax http request + response logs as well (status and payloads). However, application output says 400 bad request for your API method ivocation.

Based on your resource class you have three properties declared as `[Required]` (except Id) : `Longitude, Latitude, Estado`, but in your ajax call you are passing only `ID` and `Estado`. More likely (if you are using asp.net validation) you have 400 response because of missing required properties in your ajax request body. Try to add  missing properties `data: JSON.stringify({ Id: idmarcador, Estado: novoEstado, string: latitude, string: longitude })`

Comment: But I only need to change estado, and I need the id to indicate which will be changed. But do you think it's only because I do not have required in the id?

Comment: 1. please add ajax request + response (from browser) to make us not to guess, but troubleshoot your issue. 2. Its not because of ID. Its because you are not passing required fields in ajax : Latitude and Longitude. Either pass them in ajax (pass current value if you dont need to change them) or remove [Reuqired] attribute from those fields if they are not mandatory

Comment: They are mandatory, not to this specific function but to others. I'll add the request +  response from the browser.

Comment: I think you were right. It worked just fine when I added the latitude and longitude. Thank you very much